# How to query Rally's Lookback API based on Release Name or OID?

Tags: ruby, rally, lookbackapi

I'm using the [Rally Ruby Lookback Connection Helper](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cad56b0d4d4ba58cb091) to query Rally's Lookback API using Ruby.

Here's my `query_obj`:

```
query_obj = {
  "find" => {
    "_ProjectHierarchy": [ProjectObjectID here],
    "_TypeHierarchy" => "Defect",
    "Release" => [ReleaseObjectID here],
    "__At": [DateTime here]
  },
  "fields" => ["Severity", "State", "Name", "Release"],
  "start" => 0,
  "pagesize" => 1000,
  "hydrate": ["Severity", "State", "Release"]
}
```

I know that everything else works since I've been using this query when not querying with the additional release parameter. If anyone knows the keyword to pair with the release object id, that'd be super helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, simple mistake on my end but I'll post it just in case anyone else is trying to do the same thing: the project OID has to be the same as the project which is in the release you're trying to query. Or better yet, just remove the project parameter!